# Crashes under load – how to investigate?

Tags: crash

I'm running my RPi B in headless mode, controlling it via SSH (Raspbian).

I used to get random crashes under load, until I got a better power supply.

Now, I've found the problem has re-surfaced. I'm trying to compile a new version of Python, and it simply reboots during the `make` process. It's also crashed on other occasions, especially when it has been under heavy load.

I've removed all peripherals in order to lower the power consumption, but the issue remains.

Any ideas? I'm not sure where to begin investigating an unplanned reboot.

Comment: `sudo grep -i OOM /var/log/syslog`.

Comment: What's the rated output of your power supply?

Comment: @goldilocks a bunch of `wd_keepalive[2871]: unable to disable oom handling!`. I'll have to try to force a crash again to see if the times of these coincide with the crashes. Btw, what does this mean?

Comment: @Jacobm001 5V max. 2100 mA

Comment: That you are getting **O**ut**O**f**M**emory messages in your syslog is not promising - it means that the OS thinks there is not enough memory available and it is (desperately?) killing off processes to try to recover.  I suspect @goldilocks thinks that this compilation is going to need a lot of memory and wanted you to check.  One thought that crosses my mind is that perhaps you have a Quad-core RPi **2**B and are trying to compile using all of the  cores (with a `make -j 5`) - reducing that `-j` value will reduce the number of cores used and memory requirement at the cost of taking longer..!

Comment: @SlySven   ... >_< ...

Comment: Originally I was doing `make -j 4`, but even a regular ol' `make` triggered the issue. I dunno, it seems Raspbian isn't being very co-operative in its context switching. Is there a way to limit memory usage for a certain task?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> a bunch of `wd_keepalive[2871]: unable to disable oom handling!`. I'll have to try to force a crash again to see if the times of these coincide with the crashes...

`wd_keepalive` is a watchdog daemon described in [`man wd_keepalive`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man8/wd_keepalive.8.html).  I do not think it is installed by default, so you are probably aware of it.

The [OOM killer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory) is a kernel feature intended to keep the system up when all available physical memory is consumed.  When this happens, the system *may* become temporarily unresponsive, which may trigger your watchdog.  This would explain the spontaneous reboots, since that is what a watchdog usually does.

`/var/log/syslog` most likely contains a record of the OOM killer activity.  This is in the form of a table with columns like this:

```
[ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
```

The kernel makes its decision based on some algorithm that generally selects the process with the largest amount of memory consumed, the point being to free up as much memory as possible.  However, this does not always stop the "culprit", which may be, for example, something which rapidly forks or balloons when not much was left.  It is worth observing that there may not really be any culprit other than the one [between chair and keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error) -- everything is behaving as it is supposed to, but you are asking for too much.

At the end of the table you will find the decision made, `Out of memory: Kill process 1234 foobar` where `1234` is a pid and `foobar` is the name of the process.  Again, this does not necessarily indicate misbehavior, however, if something is misbehaving and that was not it, the OOM condition will probably reoccur quickly and you will find another table further on.  By evaluating these you should be able to figure out the details of what happened.

To be clear: The intention of the OOM killer is not to disable the system.  It is to free up memory in order to restore normal operation.  This is not always effective, and the slow down created by the OOM condition may have triggered the watchdog (which is effective, at least in terms of restarting the system).

To help prevent or diagnose the issue in the future, you could use a monitor such as `top` or `htop`.  For the long term (e.g., on a server), you could try monitoring specific processes with [plog](http://cognitivedissonance.ca/cogware/plog/).

Comment: Yes, I do recall installing this, but honestly it as so long ago I forgot. From the manpage: "Under high system load wd_keepalive might be swapped out of memory and may fail to make it back in  in  time.  Under  these
       circumstances  the  Linux  kernel will reset the machine. To make sure you won't get unnecessary reboots make sure you have
       the variable realtime set to yes in the configuration file watchdog.conf.  This adds real time support to wd_keepalive:  it
       will lock itself into memory and there should  be no problem even under the highest of loads." Hmmm...

Comment: Actually, it seems `realtime` is already set to "yes", so this won't solve the problem

Comment: At a certain point I do not think it will be able to guarantee that, and under such conditions you probably want it to trigger because the system really is unrecoverable -- for example the [fork bomb](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/41534/5538) which Jacobm001 mentioned.  Fork bombs are easy to create accidently; I believe [this recent question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/41534/5538) is an example of such (picking through the wreckage will confirm that).  Obviously `make` could lead to anything, it depends on the makefile.

Comment: I'm about to disable the watchdog as @Jacobm001 suggested, and see if I can at least `make`. Not sure what a long-term solution would be though, as I recall this happening during a lot of compiles (which eventually succeeded, given enough tries).

Comment: It could also happen that the watchdog itself is targeted, I dunno.  And of course it seems to be aware of what is going on ("unable to disable oom handling" is a message from the watchdog).

Comment: Removing the watchdog probably won't solve the underlying OOM problem, but it will make it easier to observe and analyze.

Comment: 1: Make the watchdog immune to the OOM killer. 2: give the watchdog maximum priority renice +20 watchdogpid should do it.

Comment: @Joshua do you have any more details on how to do this?

Comment: http://backdrift.org/oom-killer-how-to-create-oom-exclusions-in-linux

Answer (score 4):

`wd_keepalive[n]` is a thread from your watchdog process. N is an integer specifying the pid of whichever process it's actively watching. From what I can tell, the error is a bug in watchdog. Esentially it's either causing or receiving a fork bomb which then causes the system to crash.

Try disabling watchdog, and then run your make process.

Comment: Disabling the watchdog did indeed allow me to compile, but I don't want to disable it altogether, so it's not a lasting solution

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where the raspberry just crashed when using make.
I changed the power adapter and it worked like magic.