# Raspberry Pi randomly crashes due to python script

Tags: raspbian, python, raspicam, raspbian-jessie, cron

I asked [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41534/raspberry-pi-camera-randomly-freezes-crashes-soc) in January here on the platform and thought that the reason for my Pi crashing was the raspistill script I used. This turned out to be a false positive.

After some hassle and trying, I decided to give this issue another go and completely re-setup my RPi with the latest 
`RASPBIAN JESSIE LITE` released at `2016-03-18` and gave it another try about 20 hours ago.

After about 12 hours of operation my RPi hung up / crashed again and only a hard reboot (power cut) could fix it.

Side info, the RPi is used for weather tracking + timelapsing. It gathers weather data from BMP085, DS18b20 and DHT22 sensors. Images are taken with the [Raspberry Pi Camera module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module/) rev 1.3.

**To my setup:**

Raspbery PI model B

```
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
Release:    8.0
Codename:   jessie
Linux carbon 4.1.19+ #858 Tue Mar 15 15:52:03 GMT 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

---

```
root@hostname ~ # python --version
Python 2.7.9
root@hostname ~ # python3 --version
Python 3.4.2
```

Upon my Pi crashing I get [this message](http://paste.ee/p/8No45#a6l434Fcb5QN4ztVxBGwLl2gGNgGAdSv) in my `kern.log` file.

As one can easily see, the crash seems to be caused by my `weatherPi` script which is called every minute via a cronjob. But why?

This is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# This software is used to gather basic environmennt data from sensors
# connected to the Rapsberry Pi Model B. The gathered data is stored into 
# MySQL database and printed to the console.

import os
import sys
import re
import Adafruit_DHT
import Adafruit_BMP.BMP085 as BMP085
import MySQLdb
import time

# make sure script is run as root
euid = os.geteuid()
if euid != 0:
    print('Script not started as root. Running sudo...')
    args = ['sudo', sys.executable] + sys.argv + [os.environ]
    # the next line replaces the currently-running process with the sudo
    os.execlpe('sudo', *args)

# create timestamp
timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print('Gathering data...')
# grab humidity data from DHT22 sensor
sensor = 22
pin = 4
humidity, temperature_DHT22 = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)

# grab barometric data
sensor = BMP085.BMP085()
temperature_bmp9985 = sensor.read_temperature()
pressure_bmp9985  = (sensor.read_pressure()/100)

# grab outside temperature from ds18b20
f = open('/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00043c9677ff/w1_slave', 'r')
lines = f.read()
match = re.search('t=(-?[0-9]+)', lines)
temperature_18b20 = (float(match.group(1))/1000)

# grab cpu temperature
cpuTempFile = open( "/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp" )
cpu_temp = float(cpuTempFile.read())/1000
cpuTempFile.close()

# calculate aproximate dew point
DewPoint = ((humidity / 100) ** 0.125) * (112 + 0.9 * temperature_18b20) + (0.1 * temperature_18b20) - 112

print('Opening database connection')
# connecting to MySQL database and creating cursor
# all queries are executed by the cursor
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="HOST", user="USER", passwd="PASSWORD", db="DATABASE")
cur = db.cursor()

print('Preparing SQL statement')
sql = (('INSERT INTO `weather_data` (`t_out`, `t_out_wall`, `t_case`, `t_cpu`, `humidity`, `pressure`, `dewpoint`) VALUES ({:.2f}, {:.1f}, {:.2f}, {:.2f}, {:.2f}, {:.0f}, {:.2f});').format(temperature_18b20, temperature_DHT22, temperature_bmp9985, cpu_temp, humidity, pressure_bmp9985, DewPoint))

print('Executing SQL statement')
cur.execute(sql)
print('Commiting SQL statement')
db.commit()
print('Closing database connection')
db.close

print('Acquired data:')
print(timestamp)
print('temperature_18b20   =     {:0.2f} °C').format(temperature_18b20)
print('temperature_dht22   =     {:0.1f} °C').format(temperature_DHT22)
print('temperature_bmp9985 =     {:0.2f} °C').format(temperature_bmp9985)
print('temperature_cpu     =     {:0.2f} °C').format(cpu_temp)
print('humidity_dht22      =     {:0.1f}%').format(humidity)
print('pressure_bmp9985    =     {:0.0f} hPa').format(pressure_bmp9985)
print('dew_point           =     {:.2f} °C').format(DewPoint)
```

---

This is the crontab line I use (as root):

```
# gather weather data and commit to database  
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/weatherPi
```

---

**My questions are:**

- What exactly does take up all the RAM?
- Why is the RAM not freed up after executing the script?
- How can I resolve the issue?

---

**Additional info:**

I already tried setting a timeout for the weatherPi script I use in cron, so if the script ran longer than 10 seconds, it would be killed with signal 9. This made no difference, whatsoever.

The Pi runs overclocked at `Turbo`, but this makes no difference to the crashes (tried several settings).

If any other information is needed, please let me know. I don't know any further on how to debug this issue.

---

EDIT:

After updating my code like the following the script seems to not close anymore. First tests (with same conditions above) crashed the Pi within an hour.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# This software is used to gather basic environmennt data
# with the Rapsberry Pi Model B. This software was sepecifically
# designed for one single system

import os
import sys
import re
import Adafruit_DHT
import Adafruit_BMP.BMP085 as BMP085
import MySQLdb
import time

# make sure script is run as root
euid = os.geteuid()
if euid != 0:
    print('Script not started as root. Running sudo...')
    args = ['sudo', sys.executable] + sys.argv + [os.environ]
    # the next line replaces the currently-running process with the sudo
    os.execlpe('sudo', *args)

# create timestamp
timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print('Gathering data...')
# grab humidity data from DHT22 sensor
sensor = 22
pin = 4
humidity, temperature_DHT22 = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)

# grab barometric data
sensor = BMP085.BMP085()
temperature_bmp9985 = sensor.read_temperature()
pressure_bmp9985  = (sensor.read_pressure()/100)

# grab outside temperature from ds18b20
f = open('/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00043c9677ff/w1_slave', 'r')
lines = f.read()
f.close()
match = re.search('t=(-?[0-9]+)', lines)
temperature_18b20 = (float(match.group(1))/1000)

# grab cpu temperature
cpuTempFile = open( "/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp" )
cpu_temp = float(cpuTempFile.read())/1000
cpuTempFile.close()

# calculate aproximate dew point
DewPoint = ((humidity / 100) ** 0.125) * (112 + 0.9 * temperature_18b20) + (0.1 * temperature_18b20) - 112

print('Opening database connection')
# connecting to MySQL database and creating cursor
# all queries are executed by the cursor
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="HOST", user="USER", passwd="PASSWORD", db="DATABASE")
cur = db.cursor()

print('Preparing SQL statement')
sql = (('INSERT INTO `weather_data` (`t_out`, `t_out_wall`, `t_case`, `t_cpu`, `humidity`, `pressure`, `dewpoint`) VALUES ({:.2f}, {:.1f}, {:.2f}, {:.2f}, {:.2f}, {:.0f}, {:.2f});').format(temperature_18b20, temperature_DHT22, temperature_bmp9985, cpu_temp, humidity, pressure_bmp9985, DewPoint))

print('Executing SQL statement')
cur.execute(sql)
print('Commiting SQL statement')
db.commit()
print('Closing database connection')
cur.close()
db.close()

print('Acquired data:')
print(timestamp)
print('temperature_18b20   =     {:0.2f} °C').format(temperature_18b20)
print('temperature_dht22   =     {:0.1f} °C').format(temperature_DHT22)
print('temperature_bmp9985 =     {:0.2f} °C').format(temperature_bmp9985)
print('temperature_cpu     =     {:0.2f} °C').format(cpu_temp)
print('humidity_dht22      =     {:0.1f}%').format(humidity)
print('pressure_bmp9985    =     {:0.0f} hPa').format(pressure_bmp9985)
print('dew_point           =     {:.2f} °C').format(DewPoint)
```

Asked by tac:

Output of `cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00043c9677ff/w1_slave`

```
56 00 55 00 7f ff 0c 10 7b : crc=7b YES
56 00 55 00 7f ff 0c 10 7b t=5375
```

This is just the temperature reading of the ds18b20 I2C temperature sensor on the bus.

**Update 24.03.2016:**

After using the suggested fixes from @tac all seemed to work fine for about 24 hours. But suddenly the RPi crashed again with the same `kern.log` which indicated that there was a mass of my `weatherPi` scripts running.

My guess is that the script starts hanging if the database connection cannot be established. From the Python MySQL docs I found that you can set a timeout for `MySQLdb.connect`. I added a 15 second timeout for testing purposes.

`MySQLdb.connect(host="HOST", user="USER", passwd="PASSWORD", db="DATABASE", connect_timeout=15)`

Another change that I made was to add a `killall` to the crontab, to assure that all remaining scripts are stopped before running a new one:

```
# gather weather data and commit to database
* * * * * killall weatherPi && /usr/local/bin/weatherPi
```

Of course the connection timeout is currently redundant because of the prefixed `killall`. I currently want to see if this helps at all. After some testing of about 48 hours I will remove this command again and try out my connection timeout solution solely

Comment: You've two bugs: the file f is never closed, and the database is never closed.

Comment: Not sure if those are the cause,  but `db.close` should be `db.close()`

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Python 2?

Comment: @tac Nice one. You were too fast. I was still typing my answer when you commented :)

Comment: @PandaLion98 I typed my whole answer on a phone! :D

Comment: @tac because anything higher than python2.7 is not supported by the libraries used for the BMP085 and DHT22

Comment: @tac Same here! Phones for the win!

Comment: What are the contents of `/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00043c9677ff/w1_slave`? Just a few numbers?

Comment: Oh, I didn't even read the message log at the link earlier. Now I see.

Comment: @tac added sample output of the bus device to the question.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Related: [What's os.geteuid() do?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36122240/4532996)

Answer (score 3):

1. You're not closing your database properly. Check line 66 of your file.

   - After you're done with your database, issue a `db.close()`.
2. You're also not closing your `f` file. Check line 39.

   - Same with #1. Issue a `f.close()` after you're done using your `f` variable.

Comment: Also thanks to you for pointing this out as @tac did!

Answer (score 2):

First time I read this script, I *completely* overlooked the following.

```
euid = os.geteuid()
if euid != 0:
    print('Script not started as root. Running sudo...')
    args = ['sudo', sys.executable] + sys.argv + [os.environ]
    # the next line replaces the currently-running process with the sudo
    os.execlpe('sudo', *args)
```

Notice anything?

> the next line replaces the currently-running process with the sudo

*Oh.*

Let's take a look at that message log.

```
[ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
[   86]     0    86     2026      611       8       0       29             0 systemd-journal
[   88]     0    88     2826        0       8       0       98         -1000 systemd-udevd
[  401]     0   401     1265       27       6       0       22             0 cron
[  407]     0   407      847       21       6       0       30             0 systemd-logind
[  417]   105   417      994       34       5       0       37             0 avahi-daemon
[  420]   104   420     1370       44       6       0       41          -900 dbus-daemon
[  440]   105   440      966        5       5       0       50             0 avahi-daemon
[  458] 65534   458      570       26       5       0       26             0 thd
[  465]     0   465     1892      544       7       0      356             0 tmux
[  472]     0   472      475        1       5       0       17             0 sh
[  475]     0   475     1173       55       5       0        7             0 pilapse
[  482]     0   482     7843      314      10       0      128             0 rsyslogd
[  484]     0   484     1784       28       6       0       74             0 wpa_supplicant
[  742]     0   742      638       22       5       0       48             0 dhcpcd
[  743]     0   743     1963       28       7       0       86         -1000 sshd
[  761]   106   761     1439       79       8       0       68             0 ntpd
[  763]     0   763     1010        0       6       0       31             0 agetty
[  764]     0   764      965        0       4       0       31             0 agetty
[21469]     0 21469     1472       16       6       0       55             0 cron
[21482]     0 21482      475        0       4       0       19             0 sh
[21486]     0 21486     3865        0      10       0      964             0 weatherPi
[21506]     0 21506     1472       16       6       0       55             0 cron
[21522]     0 21522      475        0       5       0       19             0 sh
[21523]     0 21523     3865        0      10       0      964             0 weatherPi
[21540]     0 21540     1472       16       6       0       55             0 cron
[21556]     0 21556      475        0       5       0       19             0 sh
[21557]     0 21557     3865        0      11       0      964             0 weatherPi
[21577]     0 21577     1472       16       6       0       55             0 cron
[21590]     0 21590      475        0       4       0       19             0 sh
[21592]     0 21592     3865        0      11       0      964             0 weatherPi
[21611]     0 21611     1472       16       6       0       55             0 cron
[21624]     0 21624      475        0       4       0       19             0 sh
[21626]     0 21626     3865        0      11       0      964             0 weatherPi
[21650]     0 21650     1472       16       6       0       55             0 cron
[21663]     0 21663      475        0       5       0       19             0 sh
[21667]     0 21667     3865        0      11       0      964             0 weatherPi
[21769]     0 21769     1472       16       6       0       55             0 cron
[21782]     0 21782      475        0       5       0       19             0 sh
[21784]     0 21784     3865        0      10       0      964             0 weatherPi
[21801]     0 21801     1472       16       6       0       55             0 cron
[21817]     0 21817      475        0       5       0       19             0 sh
[21821]     0 21821     3865        0      11       0      964             0 weatherPi
[21840]     0 21840     1472       16       6       0       55             0 cron
[21853]     0 21853      475        0       5       0       19             0 sh
[21855]     0 21855     3865        0      11       0      964             0 weatherPi
[21877]     0 21877     1472       16       6       0       55             0 cron
[21890]     0 21890      475        0       4       0       19             0 sh
[21892]     0 21892     3865        0       9       0      964             0 weatherPi
[21911]     0 21911     1472       16       6       0       55             0 cron
[21924]     0 21924      475        0       4       0       19             0 sh
[21926]     0 21926     3865        0      10       0      964             0 weatherPi
[21948]     0 21948     1472       16       6       0       55             0 cron
[21961]     0 21961      475        0       5       0       19             0 sh
[21963]     0 21963     3865        0      10       0      964             0 weatherPi
[21982]     0 21982     1472       16       6       0       55             0 cron
[21994]     0 21994      475        0       5       0       19             0 sh
[21995]     0 21995     3865        0      10       0      964             0 weatherPi
[22014]     0 22014     1472       16       6       0       55             0 cron
[22029]     0 22029      475        0       4       0       19             0 sh
[22030]     0 22030     3865        0      11       0      964             0 weatherPi
[22053]     0 22053     1472       16       6       0       55             0 cron
[22066]     0 22066      475        0       5       0       19             0 sh
[22068]     0 22068     3865        0      11       0      964             0 weatherPi
[22085]     0 22085     1472       16       6       0       55             0 cron
[22098]     0 22098      475        0       5       0       19             0 sh
[22102]     0 22102     3865        0      11       0      964             0 weatherPi
[22138]     0 22138     1472       16       6       0       55             0 cron
[22156]     0 22156      475        0       4       0       19             0 sh
[22159]     0 22159     3865        0       9       0      964             0 weatherPi
[22696]     0 22696     1472       16       6       0       55             0 cron
[22710]     0 22710      475        0       4       0       19             0 sh
[22712]     0 22712     3865        0       9       0      964             0 weatherPi
[22945]     0 22945     1472       16       6       0       55             0 cron
[22961]     0 22961      475        0       4       0       19             0 sh
[22962]     0 22962     3865        0      11       0      964             0 weatherPi
[22977]     0 22977     1472       16       6       0       55             0 cron
[22990]     0 22990      475        0       4       0       19             0 sh
[22992]     0 22992     3865      225      10       0      739             0 weatherPi
[23016]     0 23016     1472       64       6       0        7             0 cron
[23029]     0 23029      475       19       4       0        0             0 sh
[23031]     0 23031     3865      964      11       0        0             0 weatherPi
[23048]     0 23048     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[23061]     0 23061      475       19       5       0        0             0 sh
[23063]     0 23063     3865      964      10       0        0             0 weatherPi
[23087]     0 23087     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[23103]     0 23103      475       19       5       0        0             0 sh
[23104]     0 23104     3865      964      11       0        0             0 weatherPi
[23119]     0 23119     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[23132]     0 23132      475       19       4       0        0             0 sh
[23134]     0 23134     3865      964      11       0        0             0 weatherPi
[23158]     0 23158     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[23171]     0 23171      475       19       5       0        0             0 sh
[23174]     0 23174     3865      964      10       0        0             0 weatherPi
[23190]     0 23190     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[23203]     0 23203      475       19       5       0        0             0 sh
[23205]     0 23205     3865      964      10       0        0             0 weatherPi
[23312]     0 23312     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[23325]     0 23325      475       19       5       0        0             0 sh
[23327]     0 23327     3865      964      10       0        0             0 weatherPi
[23344]     0 23344     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[23360]     0 23360      475       19       5       0        0             0 sh
[23362]     0 23362     3865      964      11       0        0             0 weatherPi
[23383]     0 23383     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[23396]     0 23396      475       19       4       0        0             0 sh
[23400]     0 23400     3865      964      10       0        0             0 weatherPi
[23415]     0 23415     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[23430]     0 23430      475       19       5       0        0             0 sh
[23431]     0 23431     3865      964      10       0        0             0 weatherPi
[23454]     0 23454     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[23469]     0 23469      475       19       5       0        0             0 sh
[23470]     0 23470     3865      964      10       0        0             0 weatherPi
[23486]     0 23486     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[23501]     0 23501      475       19       5       0        0             0 sh
[23503]     0 23503     3865      964      11       0        0             0 weatherPi
[23526]     0 23526     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[23542]     0 23542      475       19       4       0        0             0 sh
[23543]     0 23543     3865      964      10       0        0             0 weatherPi
[23558]     0 23558     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[23571]     0 23571      475       19       5       0        0             0 sh
[23573]     0 23573     3865      964      10       0        0             0 weatherPi
[23597]     0 23597     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[23610]     0 23610      475       19       5       0        0             0 sh
[23613]     0 23613     3865      964      10       0        0             0 weatherPi
[23629]     0 23629     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[23642]     0 23642      475       19       5       0        0             0 sh
[23644]     0 23644     3865      964      11       0        0             0 weatherPi
[23711]     0 23711     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[23724]     0 23724      475       19       5       0        0             0 sh
[23727]     0 23727     3865      964       9       0        0             0 weatherPi
[23743]     0 23743     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[23757]     0 23757      475       19       4       0        0             0 sh
[23758]     0 23758     3865      964      10       0        0             0 weatherPi
[23782]     0 23782     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[23795]     0 23795      475       19       5       0        0             0 sh
[23798]     0 23798     3865      964      10       0        0             0 weatherPi
[23815]     0 23815     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[23828]     0 23828      475       19       6       0        0             0 sh
[23830]     0 23830     3865      964      11       0        0             0 weatherPi
[23854]     0 23854     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[23867]     0 23867      475       19       5       0        0             0 sh
[23871]     0 23871     3865      964      11       0        0             0 weatherPi
[23886]     0 23886     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[23899]     0 23899      475       19       5       0        0             0 sh
[23901]     0 23901     3865      964      10       0        0             0 weatherPi
[24010]     0 24010     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[24022]     0 24022      475       19       5       0        0             0 sh
[24023]     0 24023     3865      964      10       0        0             0 weatherPi
[24042]     0 24042     1472       66       6       0        5             0 cron
[24055]     0 24055      475       19       5       0        0             0 sh
... 100 more lines ...
Out of memory: Kill process 24097 (weatherPi) score 7 or sacrifice child
Killed process 24097 (weatherPi) total-vm:15460kB, anon-rss:3856kB, file-rss:0kB
```

Specifically, the `name` column. `sh cron weatherPi sh cron weatherPi ....`

For whatever reason (perhaps `cron` or `sh` weren't started with `sudo`, `os.geteuid` is wrong for a number of reasons, etc), this process just spawns itself over and over again, eventually invoking the [OOM Killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer). It's what's known as a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).

It's (sort of) equivalent to `while 1: os.fork()`.

What else? Well,

```
args = ['sudo', sys.executable] + sys.argv + [os.environ]
```

???
`args` now probably resembles:

```
["sudo", "/usr/bin/python", "", {'HISTTIMEFORMAT': '%d-%m-%y %H:%M ', 'MDMSESSION': 'cinnamon', 'MDM_LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/share/cinnamon:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/usr/share/mdm/', 'MANDATORY_PATH': '/usr/share/gconf/cinnamon.mandatory.path', 'HISTSIZE': '', 'WINDOWPATH': '8', 'MANPATH': ':/usr/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man', 'XSCH_PARAM_NAME': '/usr/etc/xsch.par', 'LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI': 'qemu:///system', 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR': '/run/user/1000', 'gvm_go_name': 'go1.6', 'XDG_SESSION_ID': 'c1', 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS': 'unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-xFITmI638B,guid=0f94f5b7d8be3b5d2dd8d09d56edb8f9', 'DESKTOP_SESSION': 'cinnamon', 'MBK_VSS': 'vss', 'XFSM_PARAM_NAME': '/usr/etc/xfsm.par', 'MBK_OUT_PH': 'ap', 'DREAL_TECHNO_NAME': '/usr/etc/cmos.dreal', 'MBK_CATA_LIB': '.:/usr/cells/sxlib:/usr/cells/dp_sxlib:/usr/cells/rflib:/usr/cells/rf2lib:/usr/cells/ramlib:/usr/cells/romlib:/usr/cells/pxlib:/usr/cells/padlib', 'MBK_WORK_LIB': '.', 'MBK_SPI_MODEL': '/usr/etc/spimodel.cfg', 'gvm_pkgset_name': 'global', 'XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP': 'X-Cinnamon', 'USER': 'cat', 'XDG_VTNR': '8', 'PS1': '\\[\\e[1;35m\\]`nonzero_return`\\[\\e[1;34m\\]\\u @ \\[\\e[1;32m\\]\\h : \\[\\e[1;31m\\]\\w\\[\\e[1;32m\\]`git_prompt` \\[\\e[1;35m\\]$ \\[\\e[m\\]', 'GRAAL_TECHNO_NAME': '/usr/etc/cmos.graal', 'SESSION_MANAGER': 'local/mint-kitty:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2257,unix/mint-kitty:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2257', 'SHLVL': '1', 'DISPLAY': ':0', 'QT_ACCESSIBILITY': '1', 'WINDOWID': '88080390', 'rc': '/home/cat/.bashrc', 'CLUTTER_BACKEND': 'x11', 'XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP': 'cinnamon', 'ED': 'vim', 'GVM_VERSION': '1.0.22', 'GDMSESSION': 'cinnamon', 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH': '/home/cat/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.6/global/overlay/lib/pkgconfig:', '_': '/usr/bin/python', 'XDG_CONFIG_DIRS': '/etc/xdg/xdg-cinnamon:/etc/xdg', 'MBK_VDD': 'vdd', 'GOPATH': '/home/cat/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.6/global', 'GVM_PATH_BACKUP': '/home/cat/.gvm/bin:/home/cat/.rakudobrew/bin:/home/cat/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/site/bin:/home/cat/.rakudobrew/bin:/home/cat/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/site/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games', 'ALLIANCE_TOP': '/usr', 'HOME': '/home/cat', 'MBK_IN_LO': 'vst', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/home/cat/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.6/global/overlay/lib:', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'RDS_IN': 'cif', 'MBK_SCALE_X': '100', 'VH_DLYSFX': 'dly', 'MBK_CATAL_NAME': 'CATAL', 'GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID': 'this-is-deprecated', 'GVM_ROOT': '/home/cat/.gvm', 'USERNAME': 'cat', 'GDM_XSERVER_LOCATION': 'local', 'DESKTOP_AUTOSTART_ID': '106c5170b96fb63af14584199627359200000022570002', 'VTE_VERSION': '4002', 'DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/home/cat/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.6/global/overlay/lib:', 'GENVIEW_TECHNO_NAME': '/usr/etc/cmos.genview', 'MBK_OUT_LO': 'vst', 'DEFAULTS_PATH': '/usr/share/gconf/cinnamon.default.path', 'MONKEYSPHERE_VALIDATION_AGENT_SOCKET': 'http://127.0.0.1:40789', 'MDM_XSERVER_LOCATION': 'local', 'LOGNAME': 'cat', 'XDG_SEAT': 'seat0', 'GOROOT': '/home/cat/.gvm/gos/go1.6', 'PATH': '/home/cat/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.6/global/bin:/home/cat/.gvm/gos/go1.6/bin:/home/cat/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.6/global/overlay/bin:/home/cat/.gvm/bin:/home/cat/.gvm/bin:/home/cat/.rakudobrew/bin:/home/cat/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/site/bin:/home/cat/.rakudobrew/bin:/home/cat/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/site/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games', 'SSH_AGENT_PID': '2340', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'RDS_OUT': 'cif', 'VH_MAXERR': '10', 'MBK_C4_LIB': './cellsC4', 'HISTFILESIZE': '', 'RDS_TECHNO_NAME': '/usr/etc/cmos.rds', 'VH_PATSFX': 'pat', 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK': '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh', 'VH_BEHSFX': 'vbe', 'MBK_TARGET_LIB': '/usr/cells/sxlib', 'ELP_TECHNO_NAME': '/usr/etc/prol.elp', 'XAUTHORITY': '/tmp/.mdmVE82DY', 'OLDPWD': '/home/cat', 'XPAT_PARAM_NAME': '/usr/etc/xpat.par', 'HISTCONTROL': 'ignoredups', 'PWD': '/home/cat/projects/py', 'GVM_OVERLAY_PREFIX': '/home/cat/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.6/global/overlay', 'MBK_IN_PH': 'ap'}
```

At least, that's what it does for me. I'm not sure *why* you're adding `os.environ` to the executable args.

```
'sudo', *args
```

This is equivalent to:

```
"sudo", "sudo", "/usr/bin/python", "", # the rest of the environ from above
```

Well, that's pretty clearly wrong.

From `help(os.execlpe)`:

> execlpe(file, *args, env)
>
> Execute the executable file (which is searched for along $PATH)
>   with argument list args and environment env, replacing the current
>   process.

The arguments to `os.execlpe` should probably be:

```
os.execlpe("sudo", args, os.environ())
```

Where args is *not* unpacked.

This will probably be subject to the same bug as before, perhaps due to escalation issues on Raspbian.

So scrap that, and do the following instead:

1. in a script called `start_weatherPi.sh`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then 
       exec "python weatherPi.py"
   else 
       echo 'Need to be root!'
       exit
   fi
   ```
2. In `weatherPi.py`:

   ```
   import blah, blah, blah

   assert os.geteuid() == 0, "You need to be root! (call to geteuid didn't return 0!)"

   # rest of script as root ....
   ```

Then, put `/path/to/start_weatherPi.sh` in cron.

Spawning processes unchecked is, as we've seen, dangerous. Please: use a helper script that replaces itself with `python` instead, and don't autospawn new processes, because a fork bomb is what you get. :P

Comment: Thanks for this answer, yes this seems obvious, I fixed the issues, I'll see how this goes within the next 24 hours.

Comment: okay I fixed the issues see http://paste.ee/p/EFDat#LESFBckNvAL3bRBeP5GQhRcq66gEt0aN but now the RPi crashes within an hour. Is there anything I am missing out?

Comment: @Flatron On SE sites it's preferred that questions be self-contained, so please edit the fixed code from that link into your question, without removing the old code. I'll take a look at this and update my answer, thank you.

Comment: as requested, I added the updated code to the question itself.

Comment: Really thanks for this extended answer :) As I only run the script as root the line is redundant. I removed it and my tests are now running. I will keep you updated.

Comment: Okay, to keep you updated: As stated in my question I updated the code as you suggested. So far it looked good and worked for about 24 hours. After that the RPi crashed with the same `kern.log`. My guess is that the script hangs on the connection part, when the connection to the main server cannot be established for whatever reason. To avoid this I added `connect_timeout=15` to the `MySQLdb.connect` statement in order to avoid this. The other thing is that I updated the crontab entry and added a `killall weatherPi && ...` to assure that all remaining running scripts are killed.

Comment: @Flatron What about adding a simple locking mechanism in the script itself to avoid multiple running instances (or at least the risk of it)? E.g. check for the existence of a pid file at start up. If not found, write one and run, otherwise quit.